# VSTest Build execution - is not loading dependent project assemblies

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

I have created a Service Fabric application and added an MSTest project in the solution to test methods in the services.

For that, I have added a service project reference to `HelloWorldAPI.dll` in the MSTest project.

After this, I created an automated build definition in Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO), and I'm trying to execute Visual Studio Test cases through this build. However, I am getting the below error:

```
> Starting task: Test Assemblies **\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\tasks\VSTest\1.0.50\VSTest.ps1
Working folder: C:\a\1
Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\a\1\s\POC\ServiceFabric\HelloWorld\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll" "C:\a\1\s\POC\ServiceFabric\HelloWorld\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll"  /logger:trx
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Starting test execution, please wait...
Failed   GetHelloWorldString
Error Message:
Unable to create instance of class HelloWorld.Test.ProductContollerTest. Error: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'HelloWorldAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format..
Stack Trace:
at HelloWorld.Test.ProductContollerTest..ctor()

 - ***Error Message:***

*
**

> Unable to create instance of class
> HelloWorld.Test.ProductContollerTest. Error:
> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'HelloWorldAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
> or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
> an incorrect format..

**
*
```

Please find the attached below configuration details in Team Services:

[VSTest Configuration Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5tPM.png)

```
Stack Trace:
at HelloWorld.Test.ProductContollerTest..ctor()
Failed   GetAllProductListTest
Test Run Failed.
Results File: C:\a\1\TestResults\buildguest_TASKAGENT5-0026 2016-08-22 08_48_07.trx
Total tests: 2. Passed: 0. Failed: 2. Skipped: 0.
Test execution time: 0.4165 Seconds
System.Exception: VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: 1
Publishing Test Results...
Test results remaining: 2
Published Test Run : https://jci.visualstudio.com/Project%20-%20Microservices/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=3191&_a=runCharts
```

Is it possible to load dependent (project) assembly in the VSTest execution step?

Comment: What's the result if you run tests directly on local machine? How do you add reference? Project reference (Right click project=>Add reference=>Projects) or binary reference (Right click project=>Add reference=>Browser=>Find dll file)? Post detail test code here or share a simple projects on OneDrive.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, and it applies to my local machine too. If I run `vstest.console.exe` on the DLL directly with the appropriate test runner, this error is encountered. Works with `dotnet test`, but otherwise can't find the executable to run tests on.

Comment: which service template you used? How to add test project and what's the detail test code?

Comment: BadImageFormatException's tend to happen when you are attempting to target the incorrect platform architecture. Try changing your platform from x64 to x86

Answer (score 1):

I am too late to answer this. But today I was facing the same issue and so I thought to share my solution here. It may help someone.
**Note** - I am using Visual Studio 2017.
For me it was happening because of inconsistent processor architectures (32 bit / 64 bit) used across assemblies/projects.
To fix this, I set the architectures of all projects to 64 bit (x64). You can do this by right clicking your solution in Solution Explorer, then `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` and click on the `Configuration Manager` button.
Next I set the Default Processor Architecture of tests to x64 . You can do this by clicking on the `Test` menu > `Test Settings` > `Default Processor Architecture` > `x64`.
Make sure you are executing the library produced at the correct path - **\bin\x64**\Release\mytests.dll